# how to perform process migration using java

Tags: java, virtual-machine, process-migration

I want to move a running process (application) from one PC to anther using Java. 
What is the normal procedure to do it. I read that it is easier to move a container(virtual machine), wanted to know how it is done. Which container to use, how to run a process on it ...?. And is using containers the only option?

Edit 1:  We are implementing process migration against faults in a network of PCs . What are the even simplest ideas that we could implement to achieve that(Containers ,VM, ... ) ?

Comment: Did you mean application state migration and fail over?

Comment: @techuser what is fail over ? We are rookies in all that - help needed. From what I can understand, yes we need to migrate the state of the application, - fail over- no idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggest you to google and read application fail over, session fail over, caching. I am sure you will find a solution for your problem in that process.

Comment: @techuser read up on application fail over and session fail over, but we need to migrate a running application, i. e. the application in the other PC should  continue from where it left the other PC.